# Programming involving Import Statement Variations

Tags: python

This is the question below for anyone to have a better understanding of what needs to be mentioned in the def code.

---

Write user-defined functions with these function headers:

```
def sqrt(value):
Return a number that is the argument value raised to the argument value power.
```

For example, if the argument is 3, the return object is 3 to the power 3, which is 27.

```
def main():
Input a postive integer, call the sqrt function from the math module using 
the input value as an argument. Then, call the above sqrt function on the result
and call the sqrt function from the math module on that result. Finally, print the
input number and the final result.
```

If you use a function from an imported module when writing your function, you usually declare the import statement at the top of your code.

You can write a main program to test your functions but do not submit your main program. Just copy and paste your two function definitions into the code box below.

If you press the run button, you won't see any output. To assess your function you must submit it.

If you include a main program that has a call to your main function you will see an error that looks similar to this:

```
Error on line 15:
    main()
Error on line 9:
    my_int = int(int_string)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Take out the call to the main function to fix this error.

Here is a sample run of a main program that just calls the main function.

```
Enter a positive integer >64
The magic value for 64 is 4096.0
```

Hint:

Use a variation of the import statement when you import sqrt from math so that you can access both the sqrt from math and the sqrt function you wrote, whenever you want. You can use the built-in pow function to implement your sqrt function.

---

This is the code I have so far & I don't know where I'm going wrong:

```
from math import sqrt

def main():
  value = input('Enter a positive integer >')
  return value

def sqrt(value):
  if value == True:
    y = value**value
    print('The magic value for',value ,'is', y)
```

---

This is the error I'm encountering:

```
#TEST 1#
** ERROR **main() returned 64
* EXPECTED * None
inputs:
64

outputs:
Enter a positive integer >
**  ERROR  ** no line
* EXPECTED * The magic value for 64 is 4096.0
----------
#TEST 2#
** ERROR **main() returned 16
* EXPECTED * None
inputs:
16

outputs:
Enter a positive integer >
**  ERROR  ** no line
* EXPECTED * The magic value for 16 is 16.0
----------
#TEST 3#
** ERROR **main() returned 4
* EXPECTED * None
inputs:
4

outputs:
Enter a positive integer >
**  ERROR  ** no line
* EXPECTED * The magic value for 4 is 2.0
----------
#TEST 4#
** ERROR **sqrt(4) returned None
* EXPECTED * 256
inputs:

outputs:
----------
#TEST 5#
** ERROR **sqrt(5) returned None
* EXPECTED * 3125
inputs:

outputs:
----------
```

---

If anyone can help me or give me the correct answer, I'd appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: The instructions say that the `main` function is supposed to print the result of calling `sqrt`; it's not supposed to return anything. Your main function doesn't call `sqrt`, it doesn't print anything, and it returns the user input.

Comment: Also, if the `value` is `True`, it won't make any sense to calculate with it... what is Trueᵀʳᵘᵉ supposed to be?

Comment: Also in the sqrt function, you should be doing a simple check of if value not if value == True

Comment: @CherryDT The instructions say it should be `x**x`, e.g. "3 to the power 3"

Comment: Oh, ok, right; then the question is rather why the name is `sqrt`. In fact, now that I think about it further, that would be square root and not square anyway... it all just doesn't seem to make sense

Comment: @CherryDT The name seems to be arbitrary, it doesn't have anything to do with what the function does.

Comment: @CherryDT I'm unsure because that's the error outcome I got. When i checked it, Test 1 is 64 to the power of 64 that gives 4096.0 . In Test 2 gives 16 to 16.0 which is kind of confusing. Test 3 gives 4 to 2.0 (which is the square root of 4. That's what I'm also trying to understand.

Comment: The name of the question is based under (import statement variations). So I'm unsure if I need to import from math (square root & to the power of) and have it in a (if...elif...else) statement. Just an idea

Comment: Ah I see now, the exercise is also about naming conflicts and scope. Anyway, the values do make sense, since you are essentially doing √(√x^√x). For 64: √(√64^√64) = √(8^8) = √16777216 = 4096. For 16: √(√16^√16) = √(4^4) = √256 = 16. And for 4: √(√4^√4) = √(2^2) = √4 = 2.

Comment: @CherryDT I think I get what you're saying now. Thanks for the explaination

Answer (score 1):

The `sqrt` function is just supposed to return the result, not print anything.

```
def sqrt(value):
    return value**value
```

The `main` function is supposed to read input, call `sqrt` and `math.sqrt`, and print the input and the result from those two functions.

Since your function has the same name as the function from the `math` module, you can't use `from math import sqrt`. Your function definition will simply replace the one from the module. Use `import math` and then use `math.sqrt()`.

```
import math

def main():
    value = int(input('Enter a positive integer >'))
    result1 = math.sqrt(value) # call the sqrt function from the math module using the input value as an argument
    result2 = sqrt(result1) # call the above sqrt function on the result
    final_result = math.sqrt(result2) # call the sqrt function from the math module on that result
    print("The magic value for %d is %.1f" % (value, final_result)) # Finally, print the input number and the final result
```

Comment: @CherryDT Yeah, just realized that

Comment: sorry I was trying to understand the purpose of "%d" and "%.1f". I tried it and I'm getting Test 4 & 5 correct but not Test 1 to 3.

Comment: #TEST 1#
main() returned None
inputs:
64
outputs:
Enter a positive integer >
** ERROR ** The magic value for 64 is 6277101735386680763835789423207666416102355444464034512896.0
* EXPECTED * The magic value for 64 is 4096.0
----------
#TEST 2#
main() returned None
inputs:
16
outputs:
Enter a positive integer >
** ERROR ** The magic value for 16 is 4294967296.0
* EXPECTED * The magic value for 16 is 16.0
----------
#TEST 3#
main() returned None
inputs:
4
outputs:
Enter a positive integer >
** ERROR ** The magic value for 4 is 16.0
* EXPECTED * The magic value for 4 is 2.0

Comment: Sorry, `sqrt(value)` should have been `sqrt(value1)`, I fixed it

Comment: you meant "result1". It's already there, just wanted to notify anyone who reads the comments. It work, thank you vert much.

Comment: Can you explain what the "%d" & "%.1f"? Does it represent "%d" as "value" and "%.1f" as "final_result) that is after the percentage sign in the brackets? Could I have written print("The magic value for", value, "is", final_result")?